# Boost shared_ptr passing a derived class

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, derived-class

So I have something like so

```
class baseclass {
....
}

class derived : public baseclass {
...
}

void func(boost::shared_ptr<baseclass>& a){
//stuff
}

boost::shared_ptr<derived> foo;

func(foo);
```

Will this work? I assume not because its not the same type, however I do not posses the ability to cast it to the right type, so is there any work around that you can think of that will make this work?

Edit: the reason I can't do the cast to my knowledge is because I'm doing a sort on a vector of type `boost::shared_ptr<derived>`so I only call sort with vec.begin() and vec.end()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `shared_ptr<T>` can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<U>` whenever `T*` can be implicitly converted to `U*`. In particular, `shared_ptr<T>` is implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<T const>`, to `shared_ptr<U>` where U is an accessible base of `T`, and to `shared_ptr<void>`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members

As your code is now, though, it won't work. The implicit constuction of the `boost::shared_ptr<baseclass>` object must be bound to a const reference, or be copied to persist beyond construction.

Consider either

`void func(boost::shared_ptr<baseclass> a)`

or

`void func(const boost::shared_ptr<baseclass>& a)`

Comment: Sorry I actually do have the const in my code I just didn't put it up here.

Comment: With const& it works, however be aware that it involves temporary so bumping the refcount up/down, unlike with matching type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.  Wouldn't it have been quicker just to compile it than to ask here?

`shared_ptr` has a templated converting constructor that allows implicit conversions from `shared_ptr<D>` to `shared_ptr<B>` if (and only if) `D*` is implicitly convertible to `B*`

Comment: but would a temporary created such way happily bind to & ?

Comment: Does it do a dynamic cast under the covers to achieve this? So it will  do type checking or is it a static cast?

Comment: @BalogPal, oops, I missed the `&` although the comment on another answer indicates it's a `const&` so the temporary would work

Comment: @legion, it's an implicit conversion, you don't need type checking for a derived-to-base conversion, it's always valid!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very much surprised. You need to pass lvalue of the proper type. For that to work the class should be base class and it is not the case.

NOTE: If if your function would take the ptr by value or const& other rules would apply.